# Is there a link between autoimmune diseases and X-chromosome inactivation?

Tags: immunology, chromosome, autoimmune

I was reading about the necessity of [niche formations to adequate development of blood progenitors](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21519242) and this idea reminded me of the [patchy inactivation of the X chromosome](http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/x-chromosome-x-inactivation-323) which followed that maybe, if some of these pathways passed through X coded proteins, this might make women have different niches, that could account for the seemingly greater occurrence of auto-immune diseases in women.

Is there any sense to this idea? Was this ever researched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here is an article on it: ["The role of X-chromosome inactivation in female predisposition to autoimmunity"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC17816/)

Below see the method and results summarised.

> Using a DNA methylation assay, we have examined the X-chromosome
>   inactivation patterns in peripheral blood from normal females (n =
>   30), female patients with a variety of autoimmune diseases (n = 167).
>   No differences between patients and controls were observed. However,
>   locally skewed X-chromsome inactivation may exist in the thymus, and
>   therefore the underlying hypothesis remains to be disproved.

Comment: Not very assuring finding, but the size of sample and the heterogeneity of diseases maybe influenced the results. I have to read it again with more attention, but thanks.